# Columns based on Rows Location and ID

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[rows_2_columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsArM.png)

Col C to create new columns based on Col A and Col B. The original file is in excel if solutions is not possible in excel python/pandas will also be great. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The question does not show enough effort. First  a [complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is missing for which you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) , also you have not included what you have tried. You should edit the question to make it clearer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df)
  Location  ID Item
0        A   1    X
1        A   1    Y
2        B   1    X
3        B   1    Y
4        B   1    Z

g = df.groupby(['Location','ID']).cumcount().add(1)
df1 = (df.set_index(['Location','ID', g])['Item']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .add_prefix('Item')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)    
  Location  ID Item1 Item2 Item3
0        A   1     X     Y      
1        B   1     X     Y     Z
```